# Modern OpenGL colors

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I noticed old code has GL_AMBIENT, GL_DIFFUSE, GL_SPECULAR etc. inputs with glMaterialfv. How are those replaced in modern GLSL code?

e.g. Assuming a library importing models (Assimp) gives direct values to such color categories , can they be still used directly (on core Context)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least sort of (though, of course, in modern code, you handle most of that computation in shaders).

One typical possibility is to use `uniform`s for your ambient color(s), light position(s), eye position, etc. Then set up a couple of `varying`s that will be used to pass a diffuse color and specular color from your vertex shader to your fragment shader. Your vertex shader computes values for those `varying`s based on the `uniform` inputs.

The fragment shader then receives (for example) a texture and the `varying`s mentioned above, and combines them together (along with any other inputs you might want) to produce a final color for the fragment (which it assigns to `gl_FragColor`).

Comment: Varying is deprecated lately.

Comment: @Lela Dax: true, but it does not change the validity of the method. It's trivial to change varying to in/out pair.

Comment: Perhaps update the answer with in/out, or at least mention that they have superseded uniform/varying?